# What are the alternatives to using ADCs to authenticate to AlloyDB from a Spring Boot Java app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-alloydb

In this thread https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/AlloyDB-ORM-Support/m-p/537212 some engineer from Google said that AlloyDb doesn't have support to spring boot natively and open sourced.

So, I can not handle use Application Default Credentials (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-user-cred) and impersonate the SA.

So, Can someone confirm if i need to generates pass/user (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct) is only way to proceed (using JDBC dependencies)?

I was expecting use as cloud sql dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Add CloudSQL Starter for PostgreSQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround: refresh a short lived SA password when is needed.

```
package br.com.xyzservices.cloudSA;


import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CloudSqlAutoIamAuthnDataSource extends HikariDataSource {

    public CloudSqlAutoIamAuthnDataSource(HikariConfig configuration) {
        super(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        GoogleCredentials credentials;
        try {
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

        } catch (IOException err) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API", err);
        }

        // Scope the token to ensure it's scoped to logins only.
        GoogleCredentials scoped = credentials.createScoped(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.login");

        try {
            scoped.refresh();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        AccessToken accessToken = scoped.getAccessToken();
        return accessToken.getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Source code: https://github.com/dedeco/spring-boot-app-sa-iam-based

Answer (score 0):

Is this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-java-connector what you're looking for? It still leverages JDBC, but it has support for IAM authentication built into it, and you should be able to use default application credentials with it.

Comment: This doesn't support IAM yet!